# Late 2013 Macbook Pro Versus a Later Build

Tags: hardware, hardware-recommendation

I have a used Macbook Pro i7 late 2013 that I bought when I started my contracting work.

I was thinking of buying a new one (except 15"), but I don't know if it's truly worth making the purchase. I figure I do some homework first.

My question is: what is the difference between a i7 late 2013 and a new model? Are there any benefits?

Comment: Have you looked both models up on http://www.everymac.com ?

Comment: @nekomatic no, I'll do that right now. Thank you for the web address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing which i7, how much RAM, and what type of internal storage your 2013 system and the 2015 system you're looking at has, I can't really compare the performance of the machines. If you replace your old machine with a 2015 i7 and with at least the same amount of RAM and the same type of storage, the new one will be noticeably faster, particularly in GPU-intensive applications like Photoshop, Final Cut Pro, AutoCAD, video games, etc.

The new MacBook also has a Force Touch trackpad, which definitely feels different than the old style trackpad.

You'll also get improved battery life (from an improved battery, improved efficiency, and the fact that batteries lose capacity over time, so any new battery of equal or greater capacity will last longer than any old one.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm assuming the Intel chip would also be a new model. Haswell versus Broadwell?